# filter data for current month and 2 months in future

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I have following controller code snippet:

```
public List<User_Stats__c> getSalesReps(){
    Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;
    Sales_Rep=[Select Id, Month__c,Year__c, Rental_Revenue_Goal__c From User_Stats__c where Sales_Rep__c =: OSR and Region__c =: regnInt and District__c =: dist and Sales_Rep__c != null and Rental_Revenue_Goal__c != null ORDER BY Month__c];
    Sales_Rep.sort();
    return Sales_Rep;
}
```

I want to filter this data only for current month and two months after that. i.e. if the current month is Jan then I want data for Jan, Feb and March. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work even when current month is December and the year boundary changes. Untested ;)

```
Date today = System.today();
Date monthPlus1 = today.addMonths(1), monthPlus2 = today.addMonths(2);

List<User_Stats__c> stats = [Select Id, Month__c,Year__c
    From User_Stats__c 
    where (Month__c = :today.month() AND Year__c = :today:year())
        OR (Month__c = :monthPlus1.month() AND Year__c = :monthPlus1.year())
        OR (Month__c = :monthPlus2.month() AND Year__c = :monthPlus2.year())
    ORDER BY Year__c, Month__c];
```

You'd have to wrap this whole WHERE clause in 1 AND so you can put back the rest of your criteria...

---

It does look a bit stupid. I guess you could make a Date formula field that would have `DATE(Year__c, Month__c, 1)` in the definition and then you could use the SOQL date range literals... But the formulas aren't indexed so a full table scan would be needed depending on how selective the other criteria are...

Then again if you'd make this field (either a formula field or something set by simple workflow) your users could benefit a lot from standard date filters in reports ;)

Comment: wouldn't `month()` return an integer value? in my code, Month__c and Year__c are string value. i.e. though Month__c has values like 1,2,3.. they are in string format..

Comment: Also I desperately need help with one more question. It will be great if you can help me with that..: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24658/data-table-not-getting-rerendered

Comment: Peculiar DB design... Why, because otherwise year would be "2,014"? Check if it compiles anyway, if not - slap `String.valueOf()` around them or `.toString()` at the end maybe.

Comment: Sure! Thanks for the help. I am getting into a meeting. I will check this first thing after than and let you know if it doesn't work. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SOQL [relative date values](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_dates.htm&language=en_US) for that:

- THIS_MONTS
- NEXT_N_MONTHS

The SOQL query will look like this:

```
Select Id From Account Where DateField__c = THIS_MONTH OR DateField__c = NEXT_N_MONTHS:2
```

Comment: But in my case, the Month__c variable holds string values like "1", "2", "3" etc. Would it still work?

Comment: @Robin No it would not work, it works only with date fields. Try to use 12 if/else statements :)

Comment: @Robin Save yourself trouble and make a date field; you can have it set by a trigger or workflow rule from your existing fields. This gives you automatic indexing, will let you simplify your queries, and allow reports to run faster.